# Catch all errors and display the type of error and message

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a generic error handler, something like "when others" in Oracle. The examples that I can find all involve catching a specific expected error.

```
Try:
    some_function()
Except: #I don't know what error I'm getting
    show_me_error(type_of_error_and_message)
```

Comment: Why? If you're not planning on handling the error, why not just let it go to a 500 page?

Answer (score 43):

This is very [well-documented](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html). But may be you just need [Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry)?

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print('%s' % type(e))

>>> 
integer division or modulo by zero (<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to ask a question that was already documented. I was searching "django" when, of course, I should have been searching "python"

Comment: Actually, that didn't get me the class, after all. It was just blank. The message (in my case) was "tuple index out of range", but I also need to know that this is an "IndexError".

Comment: Python 3 syntax:   print('%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e)))

Comment: not well enough because hard to find in docs

Comment: @pankajghadge AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute 'message'

Answer (score 11):

```
import traceback

try:
    some_function()
except Exception as e:
    message = traceback.format_exc()
    print(message)
```

Comment: It will be great if you can explain your answer too.

Comment: If you use traceback, it will give the flow of your code and give you proper massage.

Comment: @NVS an output of this would explain it better

Comment: `print message` didn't work, but `print(message)` worked for me.

Comment: Yes, the answer was written in respect of python 2.7 I have updated it to python 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

To print the exception using Python 3, you'll want to use `type(e)`. Example below:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))

>>> <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```

And then you can catch the exception with:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Cannot divide by 0')
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))

>>> Cannot divide by 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an exception in Python 3:

```
try:
    # your code
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```