# Not able insert into Django modeling

Tags: python, django, django-views

my input is using JSON post request

```
{
  "rawdata": [
    {
      "id": "89729999",
      "name": "testname",
      "product": "testproduct",
      "modified_at": "2023-12-14T03:00:00.000Z",
      "modified_by": "personname",
      "asset": {
        "configname": ["testconfig"],
        "serialnumber": ["testserialnumber"],
        "owner": ["owner1","owner2"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

model.py

```
class Host(models.Model):
    id                = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    product           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modified_at       = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by       = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Hostinfo(models.Model):
    fk                = models.ForeignKey(Host, on_delete=models.CASCADE) ## id 
    parameter_section = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parameter         = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    parameter_index   = models.IntegerField()  ## index 
    value             = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    modified_at       = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

view.py

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def hostrequest(request):
    data=request.data.get('rawdata')
    print(data) 
    try:   
        for item in data:
            host=Host()
            host.cmdbid = item['id']
            host.name = item['name']
            host.product =item['product']
            host.modified_at= item['modified_at']
            host.modified_by= item['modified_by']
            host.save()
            hostparameter = Hostinfo()
           for parameter_section in item:
                if parameter_section != "id" and parameter_section != "name" and parameter_section != "product" and parameter_section != "modified_at" and parameter_section != "modified_by":
                    detailData = item[parameter_section]
                    for parameter in detailData:
                        parameters = detailData[parameter]
                        for parameter_index in parameters:
                            value = parameters[parameter_index]
                            hostparameter.fk += item['id']
                            hostparameter.parameter_section += parameter_section['parameter_section']
                            hostparameter.parameter += parameter['parameter']
                            hostparameter.parameter_index += parameter_index['parameter_index']
                            hostparameter.value += value['value']
                            hostparameter.save()
            response_data={"error":False,"Message":"Updated Successfully"}
            return JsonResponse(response_data,safe=False,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except:
        response_data={"error":True,"Message":"Failed to Update Data"}
        return JsonResponse(response_data,safe=False)
```

i executed view script without any issue but i'm only able insert value into host. But not able insert into Hostinfo.
Anyone could help on this why i not able insert into Hostinfo. Any issue on this script on view.py ?

final output on Hostinfo table

| fk | parameter_section | parameter | parameter_index | value | modified_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89.. | asset | configname | 0 | testco. | 2023-12-14.. |
| 89.. | asset | owner | 0 | owner1 | 2023-12-14.. |
| 89.. | asset | owner | 1 | owner2 | 2023-12-14.. |

[[Output of scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUlg4.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUlg4.png)

Comment: I don't see the 'cmdbid' field in the models.

Comment: i have updated, it 'id'

Comment: What's the Error message you get?

Comment: Also, I would not change the FK id. Let Django handle it.

Comment: There is no error, only able to insert into Host model. But not able to insert Hostinfo model.

Comment: I have an error here: parameters[parameter_index]. If you print parameter_index, then these are already extracted values. It also swears at fk and can’t detect it. It's true that I do everything in django without @api_view(('POST',)) decorator.

Comment: Could guide, do everything in django without @api_view(('POST',)) decorator?

Comment: I'm already trying, if it works I'll post an answer. Have you tried what parameters[parameter_index] prints?

Comment: yes, i get parameter_index ='testconfig'. but i need testconfig under value column and parameter_index should have '0'

Comment: I'm a little confused with your dictionary.
I assume everything under **asset** shall go into table 'hostinfo'?
And there, each **key** would be a hostinfo.parameter and each **value** a hostinfo.value?
If yes, why is **configname** a list. Do you expect more than one, in a single asset.configname?

Comment: yes correct, will be a more than one value.  Example : parameter_index= '0' ='owner1' and  parameter_index= '1' ='owner2'

Comment: i shown above output on Hostinfo table look like.

Comment: While trying to figure this out, remove the **try**, **except** part, so the code can throw the errors, hence helping to understand the issue.

In general, it's a good idea to only catch **known** excepts, so unknown errors can still pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented out the line with data because I moved the JSON object outside the view. Used the item['asset'] condition, checking whether it exists, and in a loop I extract `key, value`, followed by iterating over `value` in a nested loop. Since when using save() I only saved the last record, I used `Hostinfo.objects.create` to save (you can also apply it to Host. The data was saved to the database).

```
def hostrequest(request):
    #data = request.data.get('rawdata')
    try:
        for item in data['rawdata']:
            host = Host()
            host.id = item['id']
            host.name = item['name']
            host.product = item['product']
            host.modified_at = item['modified_at']
            host.modified_by = item['modified_by']
            host.save()
            r = Host.objects.get(id=item['id'])
            if item['asset']:
                for key, value in item['asset'].items():
                    if key != 'serialnumber':
                        for i in range(len(value)):
                            Hostinfo.objects.create(fk=r, parameter_section='asset',
                                                    parameter=key, parameter_index=i,
                                                    value=value[i],
                                                    modified_at=item['modified_at'])

                response_data = {"error": False, "Message": "Updated Successfully"}
                return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


    except:
        response_data = {"error": True, "Message": "Failed to Update Data"}
        return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your guide but still i'm not able insert into Hostinfo table. Output i have attached above [Output of scripts]1. it only able insert into Host table

Comment: Removed the row: hostparameter = Hostinfo(). She's not needed. Please note the entry is created: **Hostinfo.objects.create**, and in your screenshot: **hostparameter.objects.create**.

Comment: Also in the loop I extract records from 'rawdata': **for item in data['rawdata']:** that is, what is inside. And I understand that are three prints: print(f"This is fk :{r}") print(f"This is fk :{key}") print(f"This is fk :{r}") print(f "This is fk :{i}") does not print anything? To make sure that the code even falls into this block, put, for example, print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"). 
In general, just copy my code as is and use it without changing anything, taking into account that JSON object.

Comment: thank you its works now. it only have one entry of configname. other entry not insert on Hostinfo table.

Comment: You copied the code completely without changes, does this also apply to JSON?

Comment: i copied exactly and executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256290/discussion-between-shan-and-inquirer).

Comment: remove the **try** **except** and see what errors are thrown. The **catch-all except** is not helping imo

Comment: @imolitor Shan was able to save the data and as far as I understood during the chat conversation, everything worked out. That is, with **try except**, not all errors can be caught? And the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791261/catch-all-errors-and-display-the-type-of-error-and-message) may not help with all the errors.

Comment: Yes, if you **print** (i.e. log) the error, then that is helpful. Thanks for the feedback @inquirer.